# Show historical data after filter it

Tags: powerbi

I have this columns:

accounts[codig] : Accounts id (int)

accounts[date] : Daily data (short date format `yyyy-MM-dd` )

accounts[Variation]: Categorical binary variable: `Normal` or `Significant` (string)

This problem has 2 parts that I cannot put together:

Part 1. Filter `accounts[codig]`  by conditions:

```
Condition 1: accounts[date] = MAX(accounts[date])

Condition 2: accounts[Variation]="Significant"
```

I put this 2 conditions in 2 different `Slicers`

Part 2. Show historical daily data in a matrix: from 3 months to the current date, daily.

Why I cant put this 2 Parts togeather? Because when I set the Part 1, the matrix only shows the `MAX(accounts[date])` and `accounts[Variation]="Significant"` data , I mean, only 1 day (because `MAX(accounts[date])`  only show me the last day). And when I show the historical data, I dont have `conditions 1` and `2` activated.

What I want? For `accounts[codig]` that meet `condition 1` and `condition 2`, show me the historical daily data in a matrix,  from 3 months to the current date.